# R Calculate sample weights based on two socio-demographic variables and aggregate results

Tags: r, sample, weighted-data

After conducting a short survey, I have collected the results in the form of a dataframe. This is a reproducible version of what the actual data frame looks like.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df=data.frame(ID=c("1101","1102","1103","1104",
               "1105","1106","1107","1108",
               "1109","1110","1111","1112",
               "1113","1114","1115","1116",
               "1117","1118","1119","1120",
               "1121","1122","1123","1124",
               "1125","1126","1127","1128",
               "1129","1130","1131","1132",
               "1133","1134","1135","1136",
               "1137","1138","1139","1140",
               "1141","1142","1143","1144",
               "1145","1146","1147","1148",
               "1149","1150","1151","1152",
               "1153","1154","1155","1156"),
          Country=c("US","UK","Canada","Mexico",
                    "India","US","Peru","China",
                    "US","UK","Canada","Mexico",
                    "Portugal","India","Portugal","Mexico",
                    "Peru","India","Canada","Mexico",
                    "India","UK","India","Canada",
                    "US","UK","China","India",
                    "US","Mexico","Canada","Mexico",
                    "Canada","China","Canada","Canada",
                    "China","China","India","Mexico",
                    "Portugal","Portugal","Portugal","Portugal",
                    "UK","UK","UK","Peru",
                    "Peru","Mexico","US","US",
                    "Peru","Mexico","Peru","Mexico"),
          Gender=c("Male","Male","Male","Female",
                    "Female","Female","Male","Female",
                    "Female","Female","Male","Female",
                    "Male","Male","Female","Female",
                    "Female","Male","Female","Female",
                    "Female","Female","Male","Female",
                    "Male","Female","Male","Female",
                    "Female","Male","Female","Female",
                    "Male","Male","Male","Female",
                    "Male","Male","Female","Female",
                    "Male","Female","Male","Female",
                    "Male","Female","Male","Female",
                    "Male","Female","Male","Female",
                    "Male","Male","Male","Male"),
          Age=c("<25","25-35","25-35","36-45",
                ">55",">55","25-35",">55",
                "<25","25-35","25-35","36-45",
                "25-35","25-35","25-35","36-45",
                ">55","36-45","46-55","36-45",
                ">55","46-55","25-35","46-55",
                "<25","46-55","25-35","46-55",
                "25-35","25-35","46-55","36-45",
                "<25","<25",">55","36-45",
                "36-45","46-55","<25","<25",
                "<25",">55","36-45","46-55",
                "<25",">55","36-45","46-55",
                "36-45",">55","36-45","46-55",
                "<25","46-55","<25","46-55"),
          Score_Q1=c(4,4,3,2,
                  1,1,4,2,
                  1,1,1,2,
                  2,1,4,3,
                  4,3,1,1,
                  1,2,1,1,
                  1,4,1,4,
                  3,4,3,3,
                  1,3,3,1,
                  1,1,2,1,
                  1,2,1,2,
                  1,1,1,1,
                  2,2,2,2,
                  1,2,3,4),
          Score_Q2=c(1,4,1,1,
                     1,2,1,1,
                     1,4,4,4,
                     2,1,1,3,
                     4,3,1,1,
                     1,3,3,3,
                     2,4,1,2,
                     4,4,4,4,
                     1,1,1,1,
                     1,2,3,4,
                     4,4,2,1,
                     1,2,3,2,
                     1,2,1,2,
                     4,3,2,1))
```

The survey is split into the following parts-

1) **ID**: A respodent ID

2) **Country**: Country of origin of respondent

3) **Gender**: The gender of the respondent

4) **Age**: The age of the respondent

5) **Score_Q1**: The satisfaction score for Q1, on a scale from `1` (Very satisfied) to `4`(Very dissatisfied).

6) **Score_Q2**: The satisfaction score for Q2, on a scale from `1`(Very satisfied) to `4`(Very dissatisfied).

First, I convert the columns `Age`, `Gender` and `Country` to factors

```
#convert to factor
df$Country=as.factor(df$Country)
df$Gender=as.factor(df$Gender)
df$Age=as.factor(df$Age)
```

Next, I check my data to see what the ratios by socio-demographic variables looks like -

I begin with `Gender`, and see what the sample ratios are for gender by `Country`

```
#1) Gender by Country: Sample Ratio
split_gender=df %>% select(Country,Gender) %>%
  group_by(Gender,Country) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Country,Gender,n) %>%
  group_by(Country,add=TRUE) %>%
  spread(Country,n)

split_gender=data.frame(apply(split_gender, 2, as.numeric))
split_gender_sample=as.data.frame(sweep(split_gender,2,colSums(split_gender),`/`))
split_gender_sample[1,1]="Female"
split_gender_sample[2,1]="Male"
```

I do the same for `Age` by `Country`

```
#2) Age by Country: Sample Ratio
split_age=df %>% select(Country,Age) %>%
  group_by(Age,Country) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Country,Age,n) %>%
  group_by(Country,add=TRUE) %>%
  spread(Country,n)

split_age=data.frame(apply(split_age, 2, as.numeric))
split_age[is.na(split_age)] <- 0
split_age_sample=as.data.frame(sweep(split_age,2,colSums(split_age),`/`))
split_age_sample[1,1]="<25"
split_age_sample[2,1]=">55"
split_age_sample[3,1]="25-35"
split_age_sample[4,1]="36-45"
split_age_sample[5,1]="46-55"

#Clean up unwanted dataframes
rm(list=c('split_age','split_gender'))
```

The above two steps give me two data frames - `split_age_sample` & `split_gender_sample`. These dataframes contain the sample ratios for age and gender by country for my 56 respondents.

**My Objective: Calculating Sampling Weights Based on Gender & Age**

In order to make my data frame **more representative of reality**, I would like to **attribute weights to my respondents** based on the official population ratios for age and gender by country.

Following some online research, these are the latest population ratios I found for the countries I surveyed.

```
#Gender by Country
split_gender_official=data.frame(Gender=c("Female","Male"),
                                 Canada=c(0.4,0.6),
                                 China=c(0.3,0.7),
                                 India=c(0.3,0.7),
                                 Mexico=c(0.5,0.5),
                                 Peru=c(0.6,0.4),
                                 Portugal=c(0.5,0.5),
                                 UK=c(0.4,0.6),
                                 US=c(0.4,0.6))
#Age by Country
split_age_official=data.frame(Age=c("<25",">55","25-35","36-45","46-55"),
                                 Canada=c(0.1,0.3,0.3,0.2,0.1),
                                 China=c(0.3,0.05,0.35,0.1,0.2),
                                 India=c(0.5,0.05,0.35,0.05,0.05),
                                 Mexico=c(0.2,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.2),
                                 Peru=c(0.1,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.2),
                                 Portugal=c(0.2,0.1,0.05,0.05,0.6),
                                 UK=c(0.2,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.1),
                                 US=c(0.2,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.1))
```

**Desired Output**

Based on my sample ratios and the offical population ratios for both age & gender, I'd like to attribute weights to my respondents, in a separate column called `weights`.

Currently I am unable to figure out how to do this calculation.

Then, once the weights are calculated, I'd like to summarize the scores using the `weights` column. The aggregation would look something like this (except with the weights included in the calculation) -

```
#Calculate weighted overall scores by Country & Gender: example UK
weighted_aggregated_scores_gender=df %>%
  select(-Age) %>%
  group_by(Country,Gender) %>%
  filter(Country=='UK') %>%
  summarise(Q1_KPI=round(sum(Score_Q1 %in% c(1,2)/n()),2),
            Q2_KPI=round(sum(Score_Q2 %in% c(1,2)/n()),2))
```

I'd really appreciate any help I can get on the weight calculation and its usage in the aggregation step that follows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ?melt to convert your official ratios to a long format, and then ?merge with the original dataframe to get weights. summarizing is easily done with data.table

```
#Convert to long dataframe format

split_age_official <- melt(split_age_official, variable.name="Country", value.name="popratio.Age")
split_gender_official <- melt(split_gender_official , variable.name="Country", value.name="popratio.Gender")

# merge with original dataframe

df <- merge(df, split_age_official, by=c("Country", "Age"))
df <- merge(df, split_gender_official, by=c("Country", "Gender"))

# Calculated weighted scores
df$Weighted_Score_Q1.Gender <- df$Score_Q1 * df$popratio.Gender
df$Weighted_Score_Q1.Age <- df$Score_Q1 * df$popratio.Age

df$Weighted_Score_Q2.Gender <- df$Score_Q2 * df$popratio.Gender
df$Weighted_Score_Q2.Age <- df$Score_Q2 * df$popratio.Age
```

I usually prefer datatable for summarization, but you can use dplyr as well of course.

A data.table summarization would be something like:

```
library(data.table) # install.packages("data.table")
df <- data.table(df)

Weighted_Gender <- df[,list(Q1_KPI=sum(Weighted_Score_Q1.Gender, na.rm=TRUE), Q2_KPI=sum(Weighted_Score_Q2.Gender, na.rm=TRUE)), by=c("Country", "Gender")]
Weighted_Age <- df[,list(Q1_KPI=sum(Weighted_Score_Q1.Age, na.rm=TRUE), Q2_KPI=sum(Weighted_Score_Q2.Age, na.rm=TRUE)), by=c("Country", "Age")]
```

You can subset by the country you want, for example:

```
Weighted_Gender[Country=="UK"]
```